# Program state and debugger disagree

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013, protocol-buffers, visual-studio-debugging

I'm on Windows 7 using VS2013 building against the 2010 compiler (we've migrated our dev environments, but not all the projects).

I don't really know how to characterize this problem, or I'd google it. I have a pointer into a byte buffer, it's our wire protocol (the code base predates Google and their protocol buffers). We have headers that indicate an id and a type; cast the pointer into the appropriate type and you can access the data and if the data is dynamic in size, like a string field, a length. None of this should be surprising, if not a bit old school...

But what I'm seeing is I've got code that checks the field id - it should never be zero. But the condition is hitting, and when I inspect the element in the debugger, the buffer contents and pointer position are all correct - the field is non-zero.

So my questions to you:

1) How would I be able to better express this problem so I can google it?

2) Have you seen this before? Any ideas?

Comment: You're debugging in vs2013, using obj/exe files built on vs2010?

Comment: Watch the variable. In GDB you can simple "watch it". You will see if someone is changing the value.

Comment: You can use data breakpoints (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to check when a value in memory changes.

Comment: Does this happen in both production and debug code?

Comment: Is the program 64 bit while the debugger 32 bit or visa versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found. A hard to see semicolon terminated the condition; I was hitting the condition body every time. Further heap corruptions were corrected with better pointer arithmetic and "realloc(buff, size)" should be "buff = realloc(buff, size)".

Answer (score 2):

This is a long shot, but, I have seen it when the project was not built  correctly. You can try to clean the solution and rebuild it again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is regularly exercised. I've been looking at this for days.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few (combinations of) problems that can present like this.

Code that fails in a production setting but not when stepping through while debugging.   The real culprit for the failure in this case is, most often, some other unrelated code misusing a pointer (and overwriting memory it shouldn't).   The thing is, the developer gets a report of an error, and then steps through code with a debugger.   Apart from the fact of using the debugger, the other difference is that the production code is compiled with some form of "full" optimisation, while the code is recompiled without optimisation (and with symbols output) for use by the debugger.   That changes memory layout of data (and even code) in the program.  The offending code is still molesting its pointer, but something else in memory is being overwritten.   That means the symptom disappears when debugging.   The only fix to this is careful examination of other code that is executed BEFORE the point where the crash is being reported.

Another possibility is that the build process has been messed up, and is including obsolete implementations of functions that exhibit an old bug.   Try doing a "make clean" and "make build".

A third possibility is that the code does different things in debug and productions settings.   For example, there is code wrapped in `#ifdef DEBUG` ... `#endif` which is only active when debugging.   Such code is often used to product "debugging output".   It also causes change of layout of memory in the program, so affects the symptoms of pointer misuse.

In the scenario you describe, it is also possible that the typecast is invalid.  It is quite common, when casting a `char` pointer into a pointer to `X`, to implicitly assume that `X` has a specific size.   The problem is that (other than `char` types) sizes of all types are implementation defined.   This sort of mismatch (e.g. program writing the stream and program interpreting it assuming difference sizes) is a potential culprit when the code is rebuilt using a different compiler.  [This doesn't explain the symptom appearing and disappearing in debug versus production settings, but is a potential cause to look at].

Comment: To debug production code, a developer can start the production code, attach the debugger, add whatever break points are desired, and then let the code run until things get interesting. In this way, the production code with its optimizations can be debugged.

Comment: That is true, Starpilot.    However, often, when using a debugger, developers often use code built for debugging, because useful information is available in a debug build which is not present in the production executable.    Also, the point where "things get interesting" is always at some point of execution AFTER the code that triggers the problem.   Developers often wait until things "get interesting" and step forward from there, not realising they need to work backward to the real offender.

Comment: This code hasn't reached production and I haven't tried it in a release build. The protocol buffer code is > 30 years old, so that's the last culprit I'll investigate. I agree that this may be some memory layout issue.